How to Securely Input a Key to a Flask App
I am creating a flask web application in Python where a user can input a key and the web app will retrieve the file associated with that key. What is a secure way for the key to be sent over http and https? How would you implement this in a way that someone snooping on my network or who comes across a tcpdump log from that time cannot retrieve the key?

What do you need http for? Why can't you make it https only?

@Selcuk i want http bc the program is meant to be run on the local network. I feel like i should give the users the option to use http instead of a self-signed cert.

Sure, but https does what you want out of the box as the data will be encrypted between the browser and your web server, making snooping ineffective (unless there is a MITM attach, which is easier with self-signed certificates). You will have to reinvent https using Javascript or something similar if you want to enable http. Note that you can use real domain names (and CA-signed certificates) on the local network as well.

alr ty for your patience (i'm still a noob at this), i would accept this as an answer
